# Timezone Aware DAGS for Apache Airflow

Tags: python-2.7, timezone, airflow, ubuntu-18.04

On the Apache Airflow documentation they state its easy to make a DAG timezone aware. Here's the given example:

```
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")

default_args=dict(
    start_date=datetime(2016, 1, 1, tzinfo=local_tz),
    owner='Airflow'
)
```

This seems pretty simple, and I tried to emulate this so I could have my DAG run in Pacific Time, so I changed "Europe/Amsterdam" to "US/Pacific". On my Ubuntu server where I have Airflow Set up, I also did "pip3 install pendulum" as stated in the Pendulum documentation.

For some reason when I run "airflow resetdb" after updating my code, I get this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Pendulum'.

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening or how to fix it? Alternatively, is there another way that works for timezones in Apache Airflow? I've looked all over and haven't been able to get it. Thanks.

Comment: looks like airflow is not running on same python environment - make sure to activate python environment where you installed 'pendulum' before running `airflow resetdb`

Comment: Even I'm lately experiencing `Pendulum` version issue (for `Airflow`) with `pip`. Looking at the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/setup.py#L372), points to a simple solution: `pip install pendulum===1.4.4` (make sure that `pip` is installing stuff to same *`python` version* / *virtual environment* as your `Airflow`)